# why framework is needed for restful services

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am learning Restful webservices. I know there are frameworks like Jersey, RestEasy available. My question is why we need frameworks for Restful web services. What is the advantages of this. What will happen if we don't use frameworks in Restful webservices.

Please clarify my doubts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point is that frameworks tend to be thorough given all of the possibilities while using Restful services. If ou use them, you don't have to reinvent the wheel one more time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't understand clearly. Could you please explain with any small example.

Comment: What alternative would you use if you wouldn't use framework?

Comment: @Justas. Hi... I mean to ask what is the use of framework in rest services. is framework having any specific annotations.?